# textbox and button not aligned properly

Tags: c#, html, css

Textbox and button not aligned properly

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm facing problem here that my textbox and the button couldn't align properly. I tried to adjust the margin including margin top and margin bottom, they still stay exactly the same location. I am clueless on what's wrong here. Can you please help me?

Asp.Net:

```html
<asp:Panel HorizontalAlign="center" runat="server">                
  <asp:TextBox ID="SearchTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="     Search your item here." CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>  
  &nbsp;       
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="SearchOnClick" CssClass="button-add" />                     
</asp:Panel>
```

Css:

```css
.textbox {
  border: 1px solid #848484;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ede6e6;
}

.button-add {
  background-image: url(../Images/button_searchSmall.gif);
  background-size: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin-top:20px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: 1px;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Try setting: display:inline-block;

Comment: ASP is no use here we need the output HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` in  `.button-add`  and `.textbox` see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rf9qmsdj/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using margin-bottom in the textbox class, you can use margin-bottom in the button-add class. That way x amount of margin will be left under button-add and then your textbox can come. Dont put any margin command in the textbox class. 
Hope this helps!